# Setting Excel cell to Textbox.text from Visual Studio, Reference Error C#

Tags: c#, excel, reference

```
    public Excel.Application xlapp = new Excel.Application();
    public Excel.Range range;
    public Excel.Workbook workbook;
    public Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
    public string file;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        file = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Quote Sheet Template.xls");
        xlapp.Workbooks.Open(file);
        workbook = (Excel.Workbook)xlapp.ActiveWorkbook; 
        xlapp.Visible = true;
        range.get_Range("D6");
        range.Value2 = NameTake.Text;
        workbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, NameTake.Text + " Quote.xls"));
    }
```

So here's the deal... Someone puts there info (in this case their name) into a text box. Then they click button 1 to export thier name into an excel template which then saves it in thier own name.

The problem is when it gets to

```
    range.get_Range("D6"); /*and*/ range.Value2 = NameTake.Text;
```

it throws and exception saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When I try to set it to an instance (i.e)

```
    range = new Excel.Range();
```

it throws an error saying

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

probably its something really obvious. Can you guys please help me :)

UPDATED CODE:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        file = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Quote Sheet Template.xls");
        xlapp.Workbooks.Open(file);
        workbook = (Excel.Workbook)xlapp.ActiveWorkbook; 
        xlapp.Visible = true;
        range = worksheet.Cells["D6"] as Excel.Range;
        if (range != null)
        {
            //range.Value2 = NameTake.Text;
            workbook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, NameTake.Text + " Quote.xls"));
        }

    }
```

Getting Exception(for range) : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Thanks! All answers fix the range error, but I am still getting the reference exception thrown.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I've tried putting

        "this.range = worksheet.get_Range("D6",D6");"
        "this.range = worksheet.Cells[1,4] as Excel.Range;"

its still throwing the exception

Comment: I know that the reference problem is range because if I comment range out the program works it just doesn't change the value of the cell.

Comment: In the updated code where does `worksheet` get assigned? Put in checks to verify that `workbook` is not null and `worksheet` as well.

Comment: I've applied what you have said and sure enough worksheet is null. I will have to look up what to set it to as I am not familiar enough with it. You have found the reason for the exception thank you very much.

Comment: You should be able to get the *current* worksheet from the workbook. GL

Comment: worksheet = xlapp.Worksheets[1]; Did the trick ;) Have a wonderful day all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign the variable `range` in your code hence it is null and the error is appropriate.

In VSTO I work off getting the target range from the current sheet for a range such as:

```
var range = theSheet.Cells[ 1, 4 ] as Excel.Range; // [ row, column ]
```

Verify what you have is not null as you work; its just good programming. Such as check if your workbook in the above code is not null before use. Such as in my example above, I would follow with this

```
if (range != null) { ... do valid operation ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will do that from now on :) Also your answer fixed the error, but I am still getting that pesky reference exception thrown.

Comment: @JosephRand Do you mean that when you access the `Text` property it throws still? That process is running on a separate thread and you may need to `invoke` to that thread to get the info. I wrote an article [Safely Update .Net Winform from Threads or Timer Ticks](http://omegacoder.com/?p=117) about invoke.

Comment: Just double checked to make sure, I commented out range.Value2=NameTake.Text and it still gives the exception.

Comment: It has been Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need create range. Try `range = worksheet.get_Range("D6","D6");` instead `range = new Excel.Range();`

Comment: Ah, thanks. :) This answer fixed the error, but I am still getting that annoying reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `range.get_Range("D6");` with `range = worksheet.get_Range("D6");`
This is because you're trying to access `range` but it has never been initialized with any actual range.

If you're just trying to set `D6` Value2 you should simply use `worksheet.Range("D6").Value2 = NameTake.Text;` and you wouldn't even need an `Excel.Range` variable.

Comment: Thanks, either options fixed the error, but I was still getting that reference exception thrown.

Comment: Try deleting the `range` variable (simply using `worksheet.Range("D6").Value2 = NameTake.Text;` when needed) and tell me what happens.